# Using pandas drop duplicates but doesn't correctly drop the duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

First of all, I'm not sure whether it is `drop_duplicates()` fault or not.

**What I want to do:**

Import file from csv, do a `re.search` on every row, if match, keep the row inside a dictionary, if doesn't match, keep the row inside another dictionary. Make a graph out of the length of the dictionary value.

**The problem**

I have 1000 rows inside csv, but the result returns 1200.

**My code**

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# import data
filename = 'sample.csv'

# save data as data
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')

# create new dictionary for word that is true and false 
# but doesn't have the keyword in items
wordNT = {}
wordNF = {}
kaiT = {}
kaiF = {}

# if text is True
def word_in_text(word,text,label):
    match = re.search(word,text)

    if match and label == True:
        kaiT.setdefault('text', []).append(text)
    elif match and label == False:
        kaiF.setdefault('text', []).append(text)
    elif label == True and not match:
        wordNT.setdefault('text', []).append(text)
    elif label == False and not match:
        wordNF.setdefault('text', []).append(text)

# iterate every text in data
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    word_in_text('foo', row['text'], row['label'])
    word_in_text('bar', row['text'], row['label'])

# make pandas data frame out of dict
wordTDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wordNT)
wordFDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wordNF)
kaiTDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kaiT)
kaiFDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kaiF)

# drop duplicates
wordTDf = wordTDf.drop_duplicates()
wordFDf = wordFDf.drop_duplicates()
kaiTDf = kaiTDf.drop_duplicates()
kaiFDf = kaiFDf.drop_duplicates()

# count how many 
wordTrueCount = len(wordTDf.index)
wordFalseCount = len(wordFDf.index)
kaiTrueCount = len(kaiTDf.index)
kaiFalseCount = len(kaiFDf.index)

print(wordTrueCount + wordFalseCount + kaiTrueCount + kaiFalseCount)
```

When I removed the line

```
word_in_text('bar', row['text'], row['label'])
```

and only keep

```
word_in_text('foo', row['text'], row['label'])
```

`print(wordTrueCount + wordFalseCount + kaiTrueCount + kaiFalseCount)`  returns 1000 correctly, and vice versa.
But when I don't, it returns 1200 when it should only be 1000?

**CSV INPUT sample**
text,label

"hey", TRUE

"halo", FALSE

"How are you?", TRUE

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

1000

**OUTPUT**

1200

Comment: Please give example of input and expected output.

Comment: @user3471881 I edited my post, please take a look

Comment: Adjust your expected output to match the example in input please.

Comment: Look here on how to write a *good* pandas question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3471881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `word_in_text`, you update the four dict: `wordNT`, `wordNF`, `kaiT` and `kaiF`.

And you call `word_in_text` twice while iterating the dataframe:

```
# iterate every text in data
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    word_in_text('foo', row['text'], row['label'])
    word_in_text('bar', row['text'], row['label'])
```

So the searching result is the mix of the result from `'foo'` and result from `'bar'`.

Instead, you should clean up the four dict before starting a new search:

```
def search(text):
    wordNT = {}
    wordNF = {}
    kaiT = {}
    kaiF = {}

    # iterate every text in data
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        word_in_text(text, row['text'], row['label'])

    # make pandas data frame out of dict
    wordTDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wordNT)
    wordFDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(wordNF)
    kaiTDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kaiT)
    kaiFDf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(kaiF)

    # drop duplicates
    wordTDf = wordTDf.drop_duplicates()
    wordFDf = wordFDf.drop_duplicates()
    kaiTDf = kaiTDf.drop_duplicates()
    kaiFDf = kaiFDf.drop_duplicates()

    # count how many 
    wordTrueCount = len(wordTDf.index)
    wordFalseCount = len(wordFDf.index)
    kaiTrueCount = len(kaiTDf.index)
    kaiFalseCount = len(kaiFDf.index)

    print(wordTrueCount + wordFalseCount + kaiTrueCount + kaiFalseCount)

search('foo')
search('bar')
```

Comment: Yeah I actually realized that when I tried to answer @user3471881 comment. I need the count later o make a graph so instead what I did was adding the `def word_in_text(word1, word2, text, label):` like this

Comment: Hi @Sae if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.